# Where is the CUDA toolkit located on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, tensorflow, cuda, installation, ubuntu-16.04

I installed Nvidia's 375 driver and CUDA 8.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 from [Nvidia's .deb package](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-80-ga2-download-archive). I want to build TensorFlow with GPU support. This is the output of TensorFlow's `configure` script:

```
./configure                                                                            
You have bazel 0.4.5 installed.
Please specify the location of python. [Default is /usr/bin/python3]:
Found possible Python library paths:
  /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
Please input the desired Python library path to use.  Default is [/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages]

Using python library path: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with MKL support? [y/N]
No MKL support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Please specify optimization flags to use during compilation when bazel option "--config=opt" is specified [Default is -march=native]:
Do you wish to use jemalloc as the malloc implementation? [Y/n]
jemalloc enabled
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with Google Cloud Platform support? [y/N]
No Google Cloud Platform support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with Hadoop File System support? [y/N] y
Hadoop File System support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with the XLA just-in-time compiler (experimental)? [y/N]
No XLA support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with VERBS support? [y/N]
No VERBS support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with OpenCL support? [y/N]
No OpenCL support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with CUDA support? [y/N] y
CUDA support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Do you want to use clang as CUDA compiler? [y/N]
nvcc will be used as CUDA compiler
Please specify the CUDA SDK version you want to use, e.g. 7.0. [Leave empty to default to CUDA 8.0]:
Please specify the location where CUDA 8.0 toolkit is installed. Refer to README.md for more details. [Default is /usr/local/cuda]:
Invalid path to CUDA 8.0 toolkit. /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so.8.0 cannot be found
Please specify the CUDA SDK version you want to use, e.g. 7.0. [Leave empty to default to CUDA 8.0]:
```

The CUDA toolkit directory is not found at the default path, and I can't find it anywhere in `/usr`:

```
find /usr -type f -name '*cuda*'                                                       
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-151/include/linux/cuda.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-151/include/uapi/linux/cuda.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-142/include/linux/cuda.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-142/include/uapi/linux/cuda.h
/usr/lib/nvidia-384/bin/nvidia-cuda-mps-server
/usr/lib/nvidia-384/bin/nvidia-cuda-mps-control
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.55.1
/usr/share/man/man1/alt-nvidia-384-cuda-mps-control.1.gz
/usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/cuda.vim
/usr/share/vim/vim74/indent/cuda.vim
/usr/include/linux/cuda.h
```

Did I miss something in the CUDA installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .deb package I downloaded only installed the repository's metadata. As the [documentation](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/8.0/secure/Prod2/docs/sidebar/CUDA_Quick_Start_Guide.pdf?pMqazYtU3YrzLLpA6_pwd14SOox0Yj_A2Vr5TteRSOCfVSHzRqUHx52uMuPSoWM0TLndXavlSb4zjvqOX8q6s3mLYEtUICWZ45aQoY7hSS-aR2rYl9-q7QguS4uveKvMxNwcyMIAsnc6JHtzio3npqUkUqIwyScCnIhzE5HNCeT1UH7e) says (page 14), I had to install cuda after installing the package:

```sh
apt update
apt install cuda
```